# To what do these metaphors refer?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This sentence of the "Am ende" lyric belonging to 'OK Kid' doesn't make sense for me:

> lieber voll verkacken als schon im Ansatz scheiße.

Apparently it has a vulgar utterance literally, but I want to know to what ***verkacken*** and ***scheiße*** point in the background not only literally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This are not really metaphors, just idioms:

etwas [verkacken](http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=verkacken&l=deen&in=&lf=) = to screw up s.th.

[Kacke](http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=kacke&l=deen&in=&lf=) = shit, crap

etwas ist scheiße = s.th. is shitty

ansetzen = to start doing something

[im Ansatz](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=im+Ansatz) = at the outset, from the beginning (and other meanings)

So one could translate it as

> It's better to totally screw something up then to do it shittily from the beginning